# one norm of column stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

If $A$ and $B$ are both column stochastic matrix with positive entries only, then $\|A\|_1=1, \|B\|_1=1$, could anyone tell me why $\|A-B\|_1\le 2$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As opposed to $\|A-B\|_1<2$?  Or why "$2$"?

Comment: both..............................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the triangle inequality, we have $\|A-B\|_1\le \|A\|_1 + \|B\|_1 = 1 + 1 = 2.$

Comment: Can you prove the identity you have used?

Comment: No, but afaik it's a well known result; more specifically, it's a special case of [Minkowski's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality)

Comment: I don't understand how you have used that here!

Comment: What exactly? I'm asking to try to help as much as I can

Comment: How did you write $\|A-B\|_1 \le \|A\|_1+ \|B\|_1$?

Comment: Well, the matrices can be seen as vectors of a vector space with the 1-norm as the norm function; then, the triangle inequality applies as if they were vectors in $R^{n}$, like so: $\|A-B\|_1= \|A+(-B)\|_1\le \|A\|_1 + \|-B\|_1 = 1 + 1 = 2.$